# How to finish/kill Mocha/Istanbul test cycle with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, istanbul

I've been working on getting an Azure Mobile App with Node.js backend running locally and testable. I finally got everything working well and started writing my tests. Then, I learned about Istanbul/NYC for testing code coverage.

All appears to be working well, and I am able to get the code coverage file generated for all my `*.js` files, but only after I manually press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Is this the normal way for a set of `mocha` tests to end? It would seem that there would/should be some way to get to the end of a set of tests and auto-kill the Node.js/express server that was created for the test session.

I'm new to the nuts-and-bolts side of Node.js/express/mocha/nyc. Is my expectation wrong? Is there a way to do what I'd like?

Comment: are you stopping your server on mocha's `after`?

Comment: No. I'm sure how to do that. Also, I have a lot of different test files, I use the `-S` option to always process them in alphabetical order. Should I just add it to the last test file?

Comment: @lascort Last comment was for you. Forgot to include your user tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where you are lifting your server (`server.listen`) but stopping your server on a "global" `after` should be enough.

What I usually do is create a `bootstrap.test.js` and specify what should happen before and after tests there and run mocha like this:

`mocha /test/bootstrap.test.js /test/unit/**/*.test.js /test/integration/**/*.test.js`.

You need to make sure that that `after` is not inside a `describe`, so it runs after all tests have completed.

So your bootstrap.test.js should look something like this:

```
/*
    imports and stuff
*/

before(function () {
    // LIFT YOUR SERVER //
});

after(function () {
    server.close();
});
```

**EDIT:**

As for the programmatic equivalent of `Ctrl-c`, that is `process.exit(0)`

Comment: Right now, I appear to be lifting my server in each test file, and then calling `server.close()` in an `after` block for each file. I wouldn't mind getting it so that the server spun up just one time per test cycle, rather than per test file, but I'm not sure that answers my question, though. Maybe I wasn't clear (it's still a little muddy in my head), but I'm looking for the programmatic equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (which kills my process and causes Istanbul to print out my code coverage results). Thanks for answering!

Comment: The programmatic equivalent is `process.exit(0)`, but I don't think that is necessary if the server has stopped. As for lifting the server in each test suite, that is actually a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, the `process.exit(0)` command worked! I simply replaced `server.close()` with that command in the last `after` block (which is consistent because of using the `-S` option). I'm not sure what you mean by "I don't think that is necessary if the server has stopped." Even closing the server in each after block basically "stalled" my Terminal after the last test would run. Only after pressing Ctrl+C do I get the Istanbul printout and get back to a command prompt. Can you move your previous comment up into your answer, too, please? Thanks!